# How to use get_option() in Gutenberg block editor to retrieve global settings?

Tags: block-editor

I use a global settings menu in WordPress for my plugin. I use update_option to set some options there. How do I use or retrieve these options in Gutenberg e.g. the edit.js ? Or can I set block attributes in php somehow?

For example I have an option called "autoupdate"

```
<?php update_option('autoupdate', true); ?>
```

How do I retrieve this option in the default function in react:

```
export default function Edit( { attributes, setAttributes } ) {

const { autoupdate } = ????;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your option is enabled in the REST API, e.g. by using [`register_setting()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_setting/) with `'show_in_rest' => true`, you can use `wp.data.select( 'core' ).getSite()` to retrieve the value of your option, and to update the option, you can use `wp.data.dispatch( 'core' ).saveSite()`.

So for example in your case:

- To get the option value: `wp.data.select( 'core' ).getSite()?.autoupdate`
- To update the option (to `true`): `wp.data.dispatch( 'core' ).saveSite( { autoupdate: true } )`

  **Note:** This function will make an AJAX request to the [Site Settings endpoint](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/settings/), so you will need to wait a while before `getSite()` returns the *updated* options.

Example using [`useSelect` and `useDispatch`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-data/#api) in the `edit` function:

```js
// In the `edit` function:

// Get the current option value.
const autoupdate = useSelect(
    ( select ) => select( 'core' ).getSite()?.autoupdate,
    []
);

// Extract the function which saves the new option value.
const { saveSite } = useDispatch( 'core' );

// Save the new option value.
function saveAutoupdate( autoupdate ) {
    saveSite( { autoupdate } );
}

return (
    <div { ...useBlockProps() }>
        <CheckboxControl
            label="Auto-Update"
            help="Additional help text"
            checked={ !! autoupdate }
            onChange={ saveAutoupdate }
        />
    </div>
);
```

Comment: PS: `{ autoupdate }` is a shorthand for `{ autoupdate: autoupdate }`.

Comment: Wow thank you! I will try that and report